# Fullcalendar: display events as a thin vertical line or change width of events

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I would like to display some events as a thin vertical line on Fullcalendar.
Like this:
[image: You see the blue vertical line is an event]

As you can see i changed the width of an event to 4px, you can see the vertical blue line. But you can also see that the event on the same day do not take the total width of the column.

Can you help me please? I use jquery and php

Comment: What did you use to change the width of the event?

Comment: You don't have control over this except by changes to the CSS styles as you've already shown. fullCalendar's rendering engine sets the size and position of each event

Comment: @isaacsan123 i changed the css of the element like this: <a class="fc-time-grid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-not-start fc-not-end fc-draggable" style="inset: 0px 0% -637px;z-index: 1;margin-right: 20px;width: 4px;" id="event_id_41119"><div class="fc-content"><div class="fc-time" data-start="00:00" data-full="00:00 - 00:00"><span>00:00 - 00:00</span></div><div class="fc-title">ascension</div></div><div class="fc-bg"></div></a>

Comment: @ADyson so you mean i have to use eventRender callback to modify css https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventRender but how can i change the green event on the same day wich is reduce ?

Comment: Like i said, you don't really have control over it. eventRender can change each individual event separately, it cannot influence others except the one it is currently dealing with. You can't really change the events relative to each other (or at least not without writing a large amount of reasonably complex custom code, or modifying the fullcalendar source code)

Comment: I opened a ticket on the github of the fullcalendar's project.